# Need to TRUNCATE data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
UPDATE SOP60300
SET SOP60300.CUSTITEMDESC = IV00101.ITEMDESC
FROM IV00101
WHERE IV00101.ITEMNMBR = SOP60300.ITEMNMBR
```

I need to UPDATE the customer descriptions from the item descriptions. When I run the script above, it gives me the error message below. The MAX the customer description can hold is CHAR 51 and the item description is CHAR 101. I just want to cut the last 50 CHAR from so the statement will run.

It should be noted that I am using SQL Server 2008R2

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 2
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: What database? The proper answer depends on the SQL dialect supported, which means we need to know what database you're using. You should [edit] your question and add an additional tag for the DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `LEFT`. It's equivalent to `SUBSTRING(colName, 1, 1)`.
`LEFT` Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

```
SET SOP60300.CUSTITEMDESC = LEFT(IV00101.ITEMDESC, 50)
```

So its take first 50 char from the value of column.

I like LEFT, since I find it a bit cleaner, but really, there's no difference either way.

**SQL Fiddle in SQL SERVER 2008**:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad609/1

Comment: That worked. I'm new but man I love this job. Thank you Piyush

Answer (score -1):

```
SET SOP60300.CUSTITEMDESC = substring(IV00101.ITEMDESC,1,50)
```

something like that...
(note keeping the rest of your update the same)

Comment: downvoter might explain why SUBSTR is not the proper answer..?

Comment: Thank you, but I am in SQL 2008R2. substr will not work.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, it throw error:-  'SUBSTR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Didn't downvote - but it's `SUBSTRING` (not `SUBSTR`) in the T-SQL language used by SQL Server .....